# Sort 2 Arrays in Reverse in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am working on a project where i need to take in 2 Arrays and sort to print them out in decending order.

this is what i have now:

```
    string[] nPlayer = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"}
    int[] nScore = {555, 444, 333, 222, 111} 

    public void Print()
    {
        Array.Sort(nScore, nPlayer);
        PrintKeysAndValues(nPlayer, nScore);
    }

    public static void PrintKeysAndValues(String[] myKeys, int[] myValues)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myKeys.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", myKeys[i], myValues[i]);
        }
    }
```

the output I get is: (Sorted By Numbers)

```
eee    111
ddd    222
ccc    333
bbb    444
aaa    555
```

I need to get it to display in the reverse of this sort(Sorted By Numbers)

```
aaa    555
bbb    444
ccc    333
ddd    222
eee    111
```

Just a note... the numbers during input will all be random not in order...

Comment: After the sort loop through and switch all values in array first to last and last to first.Also your int[] won't compile that way.

Comment: yeah i see sorry was typing it in

Comment: since the data appears related to each other, you'd better off using a class so the score stays with the player for certain.

Comment: I have posted an easy way on how to do this below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the arrays with the Array.Revers method.

```
    public void Print()
    {
        Array.Sort(nScore, nPlayer);
        Array.Reverse(nScore);
        Array.Reverse(nPlayer);
        PrintKeysAndValues(nPlayer, nScore);
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand how this would work if "the numbers during input will all be random not in order"... wouldn't this just reverse the random order?

Comment: Also note using a class as stated to hold the data for the players is much more prefferable.

Comment: @danludwig The above first sorts the arrays based on the scores. Then it reverses both arrays keeping the data in line.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ also works and will allow you to skip the Array.Sort entirely:

```
nScore = nScore.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray();
nPlayer = nPlayter.OrderByDescending(c => c).ToArray();
PrintKeysAndValues(nPlayer, nScore);
```

Comment: with that wouldnt the player and Score be mixed up and not with same one

Comment: Don't forget you will need `using System.Linq` for this to compile though.

Comment: Whoops, yeah you are right Al... I didn't notice the relation between the two arrays. You could use a Tuple<string, int>, create a player object, or project this into a new object using LINQ's Select extension method for easy sorting. Any other method would be a hack.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the numbers array in descending order using any comparison sorting algorithm.
While sorting, the same rearrangement of elements needs to be done for the array of strings.
Are you looking for a code to do the above?

Comment: If you have an example it would help. I am currently trying to learn and C# is complex... Might just stick with ruby.

Comment: It's not really complex when you start learning from beginning